# Linking Trello cards to code commits

Tags: trello

How can I integrate a card in Trello to one or more commits in a repository, beyond simply pasting a URL?

I'm specifically interested in integration with bitbucket.org and github.com.

For example, can I configure a board to know about my repository and when I type something that looks like a hash of a commit, Trello will try to turn it into a hyperlink.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what you mean when you say link? Typically a link implies a url, but sounds like you're looking for something different.

Comment: Please see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63088/how-to-integrate-bitbucket-and-trello-create-a-card-comment-on-a-new-changeset/63089#63089

Comment: Why can't you just paste an URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is new but only available for **[Trello Business Class](https://trello.com/business-class?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=link&utm_content=top_of_post&utm_campaign=bc3)**

[Integrate Trello with GitHub](http://blog.trello.com/github-and-trello-integrate-your-commits/)