# How to integrate Bitbucket and Trello (create a card comment on a new changeset)?

Tags: trello, bitbucket, integration

I'd like to setup a simple workflow: a programmer mentions a card id in the commit message, and some information about the commit is automatically added as a comment to that Trello card. A hosted automatic solution is preferred.

What I've found so far:

- [A discussion on the Zapier forum](https://zapier.com/support/questions/117/add-comment-to-trello-card/)
- [sntran / trello-broker — host-it-yourself solution](https://bitbucket.org/sntran/trello-broker)
- [Issue on Bitbucket with useful discussion #6186 - Add broker for Trello (BB-7347)](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/6186/add-broker-for-trello-bb-7347)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some experimenting with Zapier, I've managed to create a "zap" (i.e. automatic handler) that does the following:

1. Suppose you're working on a feature which has the following Trello card: https://trello.com/c/NuSGfssX/
2. You push a commit to Bitbucket, which commit message contains `tr(NuSGfssX)`, e.g.:

   ```
   hg ci -m "Finished the very important feature tr(NuSGfssX)"
   ```
3. A new Trello card comment is automatically created, containing information about the commit.

Here is how it's done with [Zapier](https://zapier.com/):

1. Create a new zap with services BitBucket (New Changeset) and Trello (Create Comment).
2. Link your Bitbucket and Trello accounts to Zapier. I used my existing Bitbucket account, though Zapier recommends creating a separate account (which will decrease your free Bitbucket plan:). I also had problems with linking my Trello account, please ask in comments if you had them too.
3. Select your Bitbucket repository owner and name.
4. Select your Trello board and List. Both are optional: you may know only the card ID and do not care about where it is. The Card ID is permanent.
5. In the "Card" field, select "Advanced: type in a custom value". Type `{{message_tr}}`. The `tr` is the your (any) chosen identifier, the same as you will use in commit messages.
6. Setup the Comment Text. My setup is the following (contains a backlink to the bitbucket comment):

   ```
   {{message}}
   author: {{author}}
   branch: {{branch}}
   [{{node}}](https://bitbucket.org/<repo_owner>/<repo_name>/commits/{{node}}/)

   Files:

   {{files}}
   ```
7. Click "Turn the Zap on". The Zap is created and starts working.

Comment: How does zapier match to the trello cards ? Can I also use the short link? The short ID ? or Only the long id?

Comment: use the short link. You will also want to add a filter so that zapier ignores commits that do not havethe tr() in them.

Comment: good stuff @DenisGolomazov, i wasn't aware of Zapier and I looked them up.. so what you're suggesting above works, but it's free up to a point, then you're subject to the Zapier [pricing](https://zapier.com/app/settings/billing/plan/140) stuff.. right?

Comment: @abbood I've used it 1.5 years ago, so I don't know if the pricing has changed since that time. So the answer is probably yes.

Comment: @DennisGolomazov seems your template is no more there at zapier

Comment: @Arul hmmm apparently it got deleted... that's not good. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Something new : New! Trello Power-Ups For JIRA, Bitbucket, And Confluence Cloud (Plus A Cooler HipChat Integration)

http://blog.trello.com/trello-power-ups-for-jira-bitbucket-confluence-hipchat

Comment: That's a helpful link, thank you. But it does not feature the automatic workflow, only manual integration. This service (https://unito.io/upcoming.php) is also mentioned in the comments, but I haven't looked at it.